# startOnLoad is not working as expeceted

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I have created VFS based proxy service as below but property `startOnLoad="false"` is not working as expected. Even after the deployment of the proxy, we need to manually click Activate and then click disable to permanently disable VFX proxy.

But the proxy status show as disabled but the proxy is still polling FTP server in the back end. We need to manually activate and disable the proxy to permanently disable it.

Is there anyone faced this problem earlier and any fix for it. 
This issue is in WSO2 ESB 5.0

Below is my proxy configuration

```
<proxy name="MFTProxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="vfs" xmlns="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileProcessCount">1</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">NONE</parameter> 
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">60</parameter> 
<parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPUserDirIsRoot">false</parameter> 
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://XXXXXXX:password@hos‌​t/outbox</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Comment: <proxy name="MFTProxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
     transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

Comment: <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileProcessCount">1</parameter> file count 
     <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">NONE</parameter>
     <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">60</parameter>
     <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPUserDirIsRoot">false</parameter>
     <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://XXXXXXX:password@host/outbox</parameter> --Conneciton details
     <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>

Comment: my proxy configuration is as above